# Count white and black pixels

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm writing a function that count a black and white pixels.
Is there any function in `Matlab` to count white and black pixels ?
I know that I can use a size method and 2 for loops and count.
Something like this:

```
[row, column]= size(im);
cb = 0;
cw = 0;
for i=1:row
    for j=1:column
        if(im(i,j) == 0 )
            cb = cb + 1;
        end
        if(im(i,j) == 255)
            cw = cw + 1;
        end
    end
end
```

But I'm looking for some easier method. Do you know any method ?

Answer (score 5):

If `im` is a binary image then:

```
cb = sum(im(:))
cw = numel(im) - cb
```

If `im` is a greyscale image then:

```
cb = sum(im(:) == 255)
cw = sum(im(:) == 0)
```

Comment: Is there any method that I can chec if im is a binary or greyscale image ?

Comment: Grayscale images are sometimes represented as array of doubles (for performing some mathematical operations). In this case, the intensity is between 0.0 and 1.0 -- where 0 is black and 1 is 100% white.